# $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2} f(t)\, dt}{x}=0$ without continuity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, solution-verification

If I have to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\int_0^{x^2} f(t)\, dt}{x}=0$ with hypothesis that $f$ is integrable and bounded, so I don't know that my function is continous, I can't apply mean value integral theorem or de l'Hopital. So I have thought:
From boundedness I know:
$$\exists M>0: \, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\,\, -M\leq f(x)\leq M$$
Then
$$-Mx^2=\int_0^{x^2}-M\leq\int_0^{x^2} f(t)\leq \int_0^{x^2}M=Mx^2$$
Now if $x>0$ then
$$-Mx=\frac{\int_0^{x^2}-M}{x}\leq\frac{\int_0^{x^2} f(t)}{x}\leq \frac{\int_0^{x^2}M}{x}=Mx$$
instead if $x<0$ I have
$$-Mx=\frac{\int_0^{x^2}-M}{x}\geq\frac{\int_0^{x^2} f(t)}{x}\geq \frac{\int_0^{x^2}M}{x}=Mx$$
Anyway in both cases I can say that the limit is $0$.

**Question:** is it right my attempt? Above all am I right in distinguishing $x>0$ and $x<0$ and so in inverting the inequalities in this last case?

Comment: This looks perfectly fine to me, but generally if you want to prove something is $0$ it's also fine to slap absolute values around the quantity at the beginning and start the inequalities after that. This makes it easier to bundle the cases.

Comment: A slightly simpler argument is as follows: $$
\left| {\frac{1}{x}\int_0^{x^2 } {f(t)dt} } \right| \le \frac{1}{{\left| x \right|}}\int_0^{x^2 } {\left| {f(t)} \right|dt}  \le \frac{1}{{\left| x \right|}}\int_0^{x^2 } {Mdt = } M\left| x \right|.
$$ provided $|f(t)|<M$ for all $t\geq 0$ and $x\neq 0$. In this way you do not need to separate the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct, but you can simplify it by using absolute values: for $x \ne 0$ is
$$
\left| \int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt\right| \le \int_0^{x^2}| f(t)| dt \le \int_0^{x^2} M dt = M x^2
$$
and therefore
$$
\left| \frac{\int_0^{x^2} f(t) dt}{x}\right|
\le \frac{M x^2}{|x|}
=   M |x|
$$

Comment: Ok so since $M|x|$ goes to $0$ then also the LHS goes to $0$ and if the absolute value of a quantity goes to $0$ this means that the quantity goes to $0$, right?

Comment: @pawel: Yes, something converges to zero *exactly if* its absolute value converges to zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot fro explanations!

Comment: Last thing: I am right in comsidering that I can't apply mean value theorem o de l'Hopital?

Comment: @pawel: I think that you are right. Also this estimate is so simple that advanced theorems are not needed.

Comment: ok thanks! I have thought that the function is not specified to be continous...so can also be discontinous?

Comment: @pawel: One needs the function to be just bounded and Riemann integrable.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh so fro the reason why it is no specified the conitnuity the function is not necessary continous right?

Comment: @pawel: yes continuity is not needed. You can check that in this answer Martin R has not used anything related to continuity.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes yes what I wanted to understand is only if the function could be also not continous